# How to insert keyframe only "Available" in blender 2.78?

Tags: animation

There used to be a feature in insert keyframes pop up menu (press <kbd>i</kbd>).

Where is it now or how to achieve that in new blender 2.78?

[image]

This image is from internet i dont know which version of blender is this screen shot from. But this clears what i am looking for

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, could you please clarify? Please edit your question and provide some more context

Comment: What's the "Insert keyframes only used for @ashwin?  Give us an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **available** function is still there.
It does require a pre-existing keying set to add keyframes to.

In this example there are no keyframes (therefore no keying sets)

Once I add a keyframe for location, then you can add more keyframes to that set with available.

[image]